# thread resumption after wait( role of if-else)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
class Chat {
    boolean flag = false;

    public synchronized void Question(String msg) {
        if (flag) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else
             {System.out.println(msg);
        flag = true;
        notify(); }
    }

    public synchronized void Answer(String msg) {
        if (!flag) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else
            {System.out.println(msg);
        flag = false;
        notify();}
    }
}

class T1 implements Runnable {
    Chat m;
    // String[] s1 = { "Hi", "How are you ?", "I am also doing fine!" };

    String s1[] = { "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };

    public T1(Chat m1) {
        this.m = m1;
        new Thread(this, "Question").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
            m.Question(s1[i]);
        }
    }
}

class T2 implements Runnable {
    Chat m;
    // String[] s2 = { "Hi", "I am good, what about you?", "Great!" };
    String s2[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

    public T2(Chat m2) {
        this.m = m2;
        new Thread(this, "Answer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
            m.Answer(s2[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class TestThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chat m = new Chat();
        new T1(m);
        new T2(m);
    }
}
```

//

**the above code works fine if i remove the "else" in both the synchronized methods.
but aren't we essentially implying an if-else condition without mentioning it explicitly?
i.e. aren't we doing

```
if( flag check) 
..
else??
```

or does the thread resume from after the if block after being notified?**

Comment: use curly braces in your else blocks.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen..i cant't believe i missed that..but still , it is giving a funny output

Answer (score 2):

When you ask

> does the thread resume from after the if block after being notified?

the thread, once notified, resumes from the wait call that it previously entered. It has to leave the wait call, but before it can do that it has to acquire the lock that it gave up when it started waiting. It can't resume from anywhere else.

In an example with only two threads going back and forth you may be able to get away with some things that won't work otherwise. In general you can have cases where multiple threads are contending for a lock and making changes, and there is no guarantee the flag will be in the same state it was in when the thread started waiting. That's the main reason that wait needs to be done in a loop, so that once the thread re-acquires the lock it can check what the current status of the condition is. (There is also the possibility that the thread can wake up without any notification at all.)

Comment: woah.are you really 93 years old ?
the second paragraph of your answer flew waayyy over my head..but mayb that's cause my head is throbbing with pain right now.will come back tomorrow and take a looksie

Comment: so in short , the thread will resume from the else block ?? yes or no?

Comment: @user2837260: welcome to multithreading, it only gets worse from here :-) . no. the thread resumes from the same wait method call where it left off. the thread gives up the lock and goes dormant but it doesn't leave the wait method until it wakes up.

Comment: yes..but the else block follows the wait statement in this case ..so ...?

Comment: and that question about age :P

Comment: @user2837260: so when the thread resumes it has to reacquire the lock, leave the wait, then go on about its business. the else is still a long way off. this may seem like an unimportant distinction but it will become apparent when you figure out the 2nd paragraph.  also what answer you pick and how long you want to wait are entirely up to you, no problem.

Comment: got some figuring out to do myslef

Comment: @user2837260: this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/25474721/217324 is very similar, you might see if my answer there helps.