# Does the waiting thread revisit the code inside synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I was reading about thread synchronisation and wait/notify constructs from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). It states that

> When wait is invoked, the thread releases the lock and suspends execution. At some future time, another thread will acquire the same lock and invoke Object.notifyAll, informing all threads waiting on that lock that something important has happened.
>
> Some time after the second thread has released the lock, the first thread reacquires the lock and resumes by returning from the invocation of wait.

AFAIK, if there are multiple threads which can compete for the lock when the first thread is awaken by the `notify`, any one of them can get to own the lock on that object. My question is, if this first thread itself re-acquires the lock, does it have to start all over from the beginning of the synchronized method (which means, it again executes the code before the while loop checking wait() condition) or does it just pause at the `wait()` line?

```
// Does the waiting thread come back here while trying to own the
// lock (competing with others)?
public synchronized notifyJoy() {
    // Some code  => Does this piece of code gets executed again then in case
    // waiting thread restarts its execution from the method after it is notified?
    while (!joy) {
        try {
            // Does the waiting thread stay here while trying to re-acquire
            // the lock?
            wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    // Some other code
}
```

Comment: No. A waiting thread will resume from the `wait` command.

Comment: @laune I understand that wait/notify is primarily used for signaling, while synchronized is used for lock access. My only confusion is whether the thread after changing its state from `waiting` to `blocked` and then to `runnable`, it resumes from where it left or it has to go back and restart. @Boris seems to have answered it in the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method only gets exited when the thread executing it finishes executing its run method, whether by returning normally or having an exception be thrown that goes uncaught within that run method. The only way for your method to *not* get executed until one of those things above happens is for the JVM to be killed out from under you (with java.lang.System.exit, killing the java process with kill -9, etc.), or if the method is being run in a daemon thread where the JVM is shutting down. There's nothing weird going on here. The thread that waits gives up the lock and goes dormant, but it doesn't somehow leave off executing the method.

The thread awakened from its call to wait never went anywhere; the whole time that the thread was waiting it was still in the wait method. Before it can leave the wait method it first has to acquire the lock that it gave up in order to start waiting. Then it needs to retest whatever condition it needs to check before it can know whether to keep on waiting.

This is why [the guarded blocks tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) tells you that waits have to be done in a loop:

> The invocation of wait does not return until another thread has issued a notification that some special event may have occurred — though not necessarily the event this thread is waiting for:

```
public synchronized void guardedJoy() {
    // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
    // be the event we're waiting for.
    while(!joy) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}
```

> Note: Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true.

(The wording used by the tutorial is misleading; the word "interrupt" should be "notification". Also it is unfortunate that the tutorial code shown eats the InterruptedException without setting the interrupt flag, it would be better to let the InterruptedException be thrown from this method and not catch it at all.)

If the thread did "start over" then this loop wouldn't be required; your code would start at the beginning of the method, acquire the lock, and test the condition being waited on.

Comment: The docs also say only one  thread can be inside that block at once. How is it possible that a thread is inside that block having executed some of the block and waiting and some other thread that has the lock can also execute some or all of that block? Technically, there are two threads - though one is waiting -  thus violating the principle of "only one thread is allowed inside a sychronized .method/block"

Comment: @veritas: you’re  right that a thread is in the wait method while another method is executing the other code in the method. Only one thread has the lock. For that matter there can be more than one of the waiting threads since they don’t have the lock.

Comment: So what you're saying is the docs actually mean only one thread can "have" a lock on the method and not necessarily that only one thread can be "inside" that method because technically - as you said - multiple threads can be waiting "inside" that method but only one executing?

This still makes me nervous. Even if some threads are waiting inside and have lost the monitor,  they may have modified some variables before they entered wait(), can't they? Is the onus of not doing this on the programmer?

Comment: @veritas: the lock isn’t on the method, here it’s on the object that the method is called on. If a thread modified something before waiting it would have had the lock held. But yes when a thread wakes up from waiting it has to acquire the lock again, and then it should check to see what the current state is. That’s why my answer said to use a loop to check the condition, so it is checked again when the thread wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

Thread execution starts directly after the call to wait. It does not restart the block from the beginning. wait() can be roughly implemented similar to

```
public void wait() {
    release_monitor();
    wait_monitor();
    acquire_monitor();
}
```

This is no where near how it is actually implemented, it is just a rough idea of what goes on behind the scenes. Each Object has a monitor associated with it that can acquired and released. Only one thread can hold the monitor at a time and a thread can acquire a monitor recursively with no issue. A call to wait on an Object releases the monitor allowing another thread to acquire it. The waiting thread then waits until it is woken up by a call to notify/notifyAll. Upon being woken up the waiting thread waits again to require the Object's monitor and returns to the calling code.

Example:

```
private Object LOCK = new Object;
private int num = 0;
public int get() {
    synchronized( LOCK ) {
        System.out.println( "Entering get block." );

        LOCK.wait();

        return num;
    }
}

public void set( int num ) {
    synchronized( LOCK ) {
        System.out.println( "Entering set block." );

        this.num = num;

        LOCK.notify();
     }
}
```

`"Entering get block."` will only be printed once for each call to `get()`

Comment: Your example is prone to "lost notification".  If thread A calls get() _before_ thread B calls set(), then it probably† will work the way you imagine, but if thread B calls set() first, and only one time, then thread A will wait() forever.  A foo.notify() call does not do anything if some other thread is not already waiting in a foo.wait() call.  [† read about "spurious wakeups"].

Comment: @jameslarge, Ya it's a bad example, but was written to show that the block is only executed once rather than for good style.

Comment: Make sure you wait in a loop. Recursive acquires by the same thread is called *reentrancy*. A wait method holds a queue of threads that want the monitor, and acts like a gate, not like something that you acquire.